# Smoothness of vector field equivalent to smoothness of its components in any chart

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I'm studying Newman's Semi-Riemannian Geometry book and covered the proof of this theorem (using Einstein summation convention throughout):

> A vector field $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is smooth iff its components are smooth in any coordinate chart.

The $\implies$ proof there is a bit contrived for me.

> Let $X=X^i(\partial/\partial x^i)$ be the local coordinate expression of $X$ w.r.t. chart $(U,x^i)$, and let $p\in U$. Since $x^i$ is a function in $C^{\infty}(U)$, (by some previous theorem) there is a function $\tilde x^i$ in $C^{\infty}(M)$ and a neighborhood $\tilde U\subseteq U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $x^i$ and $\tilde x^i$ agree on $\tilde U$. Thus
> $$X(\tilde x^i)=\alpha^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(\tilde x^i)=\alpha^i$$ on $\tilde U$. Since $X$ is smooth and $\tilde x^i\in C^{\infty}(M)$, then $X(\tilde x^i)\in C^{\infty}(M)$. So $\tilde\alpha^i$ is smooth on $\tilde U$, and since $p$ was arbitrary, $\alpha^i$ is smooth on $U$.

Now my question is what's the purpose behind this elaborate construction of $\tilde U$? Can't we just do it like this:

Let $X$ be smooth and $(U,x^i)$ be some chart. Let $\{\partial/\partial x^i\}$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) be a local frame in that chart, and let $\alpha^i$ be components of $X$ w.r.t. that chart. Act $X$ on the $x^j$ coordinate function to get:
$$X(x^j)=\alpha^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(x^j)=\alpha^j$$

Since the LHS is a smooth vector field acting on a $C^{\infty}(U)$ function, the RHS is also a $C^{\infty}(U)$ function.

Isn't this a much simpler proof of the $\implies$ statement? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: This depends on your definition of a vector field/tangent vectors. Presumably the author has defined vector fields as acting on $C^\infty (M)$ functions, meaning that you can not feed $x^j$ to $X$ (because $x^j$ is only defined on $U$ and not on $M$).

Comment: @jd27: I see. So the author defined components of a $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ w.r.t. a chart $(U,x^i)$ as $X\ |_U=\alpha^i(\partial/\partial x^i)$. He also says that for brevity we denote $X\ |_U$ by just $X$ and that it should be clear from the context. So in the main theorem statement, when he says "components of $X$ in any coordinate chart", it should mean "for any coordinate chart $(U,x^i)$, components of $X\ |_U$ w.r.t. that chart". I think by that logic, my proof should work?

Comment: It depends on the way the tangent space is defined. If a tangent vector is a derivation $C^\infty ( M) \to \mathbb{R}$, then we need to apply $X$ to a function that is in $C^\infty ( M) $. Note that the author really is applying $X$ to $\tilde{x}^i$ here and not $X|_U$.

Comment: @jd27: Thanks for the clarification! I think I see your point. The author indeed defines a tangent vector as a derivation. BUT at the same time, he also says that we can take $U$ as a submanifold of $M$, and $X\ |_U$ is the restriction of $X$ to $U$ - i.e. $X\ |_U$ is a derivation on $U$. So $X(x^j)$ in the equation I wrote would then mean $X\ |_U(x^j)$

Comment: Presumably you mean that $X|_U$ is a vector field on $U$, not a derivation? Anyways if you argue with $X|_U$ (as a vector field on $U$) here you need to use the fact that $T_pU = T_pM $ for all $p \in U$, but that uses the same partition of unity argument as the author is using here.